# how can i use react redux in class component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-form

im a new to redux, and i want to know if it possible to use redux in class component.
we know that hooks works only in function component, so i export a function to use `useSelector` to access the store :

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function Selector() {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  return counter;
}
```

and import it to the `compone` component so will be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import selector from "../Store/selector";

export class Compone extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(selector());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>
          Counter: <span>0</span>
        </h1>
        <button style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}>Increase</button>
        <button>Decrease</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Compone;
```

and i import `compone` component to the `App` root component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Compone from "../components/compone/Compone";
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Compone />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

so this didn't work for me, is there a way to use redux in class component?,

how to use redux in class component,
how to use react redux in class component,

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create some `actions` and some `reducers`. 
Then you need to create a `store` using the reducers. 
After that you can use `connect` method of `react-redux` with your class component.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: You can use this [github repository](https://github.com/ClassHacker/tic-tac-toe/tree/main/app-client/src) for reference.